# Проблема с включением заголовочных файлов  "error: redefinition of"

Tags: c, кросс-компиляция, linux

При кросскомпиляции драйвера под  OpenWRT- ядро - 2.6.39.4

выскакивает ошибка **error: redefinition of....**

Фрагмент кода:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,26)
#include <linux/unaligned/access_ok.h>
#else

 static inline u16 get_unaligned_le16(const void *p)
{
    return le16_to_cpup((__le16 *)p);
}

static inline u32 get_unaligned_le32(const void *p)
{
    return le32_to_cpup((__le32 *)p);
}

static inline void put_unaligned_le16(u16 val, void *p)
{
    *((__le16 *)p) = cpu_to_le16(val);
}

static inline void put_unaligned_le32(u32 val, void *p)
{
    *((__le32 *)p) = cpu_to_le32(val);
} 
#endif
```

Репорт компилятора:

```
In file included from drivers/net/usb/hw_cdc_driver.c:132:0:
include/linux/unaligned/access_ok.h:7:19: error: redefinition of 'get_unaligned_le16'
include/linux/unaligned/le_struct.h:6:19: note: previous definition of 'get_unaligned_le16' was here
include/linux/unaligned/access_ok.h:12:19: error: redefinition of 'get_unaligned_le32'
include/linux/unaligned/le_struct.h:11:19: note: previous definition of 'get_unaligned_le32' was here
include/linux/unaligned/access_ok.h:17:19: error: redefinition of 'get_unaligned_le64'
include/linux/unaligned/le_struct.h:16:19: note: previous definition of 'get_unaligned_le64' was here
include/linux/unaligned/access_ok.h:22:19: error: redefinition of 'get_unaligned_be16'
include/linux/unaligned/be_byteshift.h:40:19: note: previous definition of 'get_unaligned_be16' was here
```

Как я понимаю, компилятор проверяет версию ядра и пытается скопировать содержание заголовочного файла linux/unaligned/access_ok.h, которое уже есть в коде.  И это избыточное включение компилятору не нравится.

Пробовал менять версию ядра, закомментить условия включения заголовка - не помогает .
Смущает то, что при компиляции драйвера под Debian ( ядро 2.6.32-5-686) всё собирается нормально. Проверял заголовочные файлы access_ok.h - и в Debian и в указанной версии OpenWRT - они идентичны.

Пробовал включить в заголовочные файлы

```
#pragma once
```

но мипселовский gcc похоже не понимает.

Что изменить, чтобы скомпилировался?

Comment: @margosh Вряд ли это "он проверяет" что-то в первой директиве, поскольку человек просто пытается собрать какой-то драйвер. `LINUX_VERSION` определен в `<linux/version.h>` и никак не связан с временем выполнения.

@Руслан Напишите, как именно вы засетапили кросс-компиляцию, думаю, дело в этом. Предполагаю, что достаточно будет руками поправить сгенеренный мейк или что-нибудь в таком духе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за различий в исходниках (заголовочных файлах asm/unaligned.h) используемой версии ядра и той, под которую создавался драйвер,  при компиляции происходило избыточное включение заголовочного файла **linux/unaligned/access_ok.h** . Я разобрал цепочку включения хедеров и вот что получилось

```
    #include <linux/netdevice.h>
    #include <linux/etherdevice.h>  /*---- включает <linux/netdevice.h> -> использует linux/unaligned/access_ok.h если позволяют аппаратные возможности платформы -
"If an architecture can handle unaligned accesses in hardware,
it may want to use the linux/unaligned/access_ok.h implementation
 instead." - тот самый случай! ----*/

    #include <linux/ethtool.h>
    #include <linux/workqueue.h>

    ---
    ---
    ---
    #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,26)
    #include <linux/unaligned/access_ok.h> /* Здесь содержание 'access_ok.h' включается еще раз, если версия ядра больше или равна 2,6,26 */
// Далее идет содержание access_ok.h для компиляции под версию ядра меньше 2,6,26
```

Гарда #ifndef ... #define...  #endif не сработала, поскольку хедер access_ok.h включался не явным инклудом, а по-другому.

Проблему решил закомментировав полностью приведенный в вопросе фрагмент. Спасибо всем, кто помогал в решении.